# Spring unable to autowire ConnectionFactory for RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I am trying to follow this simple [guide for Spring RabbitMQ messaging](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/).

I have 2 issues with autowiring:

1. Could not autowire. No beans of 'ConnectionFactory' type found
2. Could not autowire. No beans of 'RabbitTemplate' type found.

I can't find what I'm missing, because the tutorial states that:

Spring Boot automatically creates a connection factory and a RabbitTemplate, reducing the amount of code you have to write.

Here is my pom.xml in case I'm missing something there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RabbitMQDemoApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RabbitMQDemoApp</name>
    <description>RabbitMQDemoApp</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was in version of Spring Boot. It doesn't create beans `ConnectionFactory` and `RabbitTemplate` automatically in version `2.7.0`....When I downgraded Spring Boot to version `2.6.8`, everything worked fine.

Otherwise in case you want to use Spring Boot 2.7.0, you will need to create these beans yourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot creates these beans, it is a problem with IDEA(if you use it). Here is the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289633/Spring-Boot-new-auto-configuration-registration-in-v-27).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the IDE and not the version of the Spring framework.
I can confirm because I was able to compile it even run it even though  IntelliJ was complaining about the error.
Here is a screenshot of the Gradle build file which shows the version  of Spring boot and Java
[image]

This is what IntelliJ says
[image]

I created a fresh project and downgraded to the 2.6.11 version of Boot but kept same version of Java and everything seemed ok with IntelliJ now.

[image]

Its an IDE specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

we have two kind of ConnectionFactory class

- org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
- com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory

be sure use first one

```
@Bean("rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
public RabbitListenerContainerFactory<?> rabbitFactory
        (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    var factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```